# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'if'

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int factor(int n);

    int main()
    { 
        int f,n;

    // Get user input

        cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        cin >> n;

    // Call factorial function

        f = factor(n);

    // Output results

        cout << n << "! = " << f << endl;

        int factor (int n)
            if(n <=1)
            {
             return 1;
            }
            else
            {
             int c = n * (n-1);
             return c;
            }
     };
```

I am getting an error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'if'
I was curious if I was missing something simple. I am fairly new to C++.

Comment: Whenever you get a syntax error message that you don't understand, the first thing to do is to begin removing (or commenting out) code until the message goes away.

Comment: You have the function `int factor (int n)` defined inside the function `main()` ... you should define it outside.

Comment: Define `factor` before `main`, and call it `factorial`.

Comment: I wonder. The first thing I would try when I would get a "missing thingy" error in any programming language, is insert the missing thingy and recompile. Did you try that at all?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to define the function `factor` within the function `main`. That's not allowed in C++. Also, the function body for `factor` needs braces:

```
int factor(int n)
{
    // function body
}

int main()
{
    // function body, factor visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the factor function out of the main function and put the code inside bracelets.